# changing the activation function or network size in LSTM does not change the graph

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to plot the LSTM prediction, but when I change the activation function or network size nothing changes in the plot. Here is my code and I will attach the plot figure:

```
y_pred_FF = model_LSTM.predict(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1))

plt.plot(y_test, "b-+", label='Ground truth', color = "red")
plt.plot(y_pred_FF, "b-", label='Internet Traffic prediction', color = "blue")
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(0,18)
plt.xlim(0,200)
plt.xlabel('Time instannces', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Activity', fontsize=16)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSh65.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code snippet, you use the Keras library to train and predict with an LSTM model. However, where you are changing the activation function or network size is unclear.
To modify the activation function or network size of the LSTM model, you need to make changes to the model architecture before training it.

```
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
    
    model_LSTM = Sequential()
    model_LSTM.add(LSTM(units=64, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(1,)))
    model_LSTM.add(Dense(units=1))
    
    # Compile and train the model
    
    # ...
    
    # Make predictions and plot the results
    y_pred_FF = model_LSTM.predict(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1))
    
    # Plotting code
    plt.plot(y_test, "b-+", label='Ground truth', color="red")
    plt.plot(y_pred_FF, "b-", label='Internet Traffic prediction', color="blue")
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim(0, 18)
    plt.xlim(0, 200)
    plt.xlabel('Time instances', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('Activity', fontsize=16)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

I set the activation function of the LSTM layer to the sigmoid function `(activation='sigmoid')` and changed the number of units in the LSTM layer to 64 `(units=64)`. You can modify these values according to your requirements.

You can find detailed information about the LSTM layer in Keras, including various parameters and usage examples. [Documentation Link 1](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) [Documentation Link 2](https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/) [GitHub Link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples)

Comment: You can find detailed information about the LSTM layer in Keras, including various parameters and usage examples.

Documentation Link: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/
Documentation Link: https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/
GitHub Link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples

Comment: The plot of activity function works accurately according the function and size it changes, but when I want to plot the prediction it's the same plot for all functions and I still don't have the answer for that problem.

Comment: Okay. Are you retraining the model after modifying the activation function or network size? If you modify the architecture without retraining the model, the predictions will remain the same. Also, make sure you use the correct model instance when making predictions. Ensure that the `model_LSTM` instance you're using to make predictions is the same one you trained with the modified architecture.

Comment: In some cases also, you have to check if the data input to the model is correctly reshaped. In your code snippet, you're reshaping `X_test` using `X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1)`. Verify that this reshaping is appropriate for your data and matches the input shape the model expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also double-check if the model weights are being updated after retraining. If the weights are not updated, the predictions will remain the same regardless of any changes made to the model architecture. I believe this will help in checking the weights...

```
#Initial training of model
model_LSTM.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

# Get the weights before training
weights_before = model_LSTM.get_weights()

# Train the model again
model_LSTM.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

# Get the weights after training
weights_after = model_LSTM.get_weights()

# Compare the weights
weights_changed = any([np.any(w_before != w_after) for w_before, w_after in zip(weights_before, weights_after)])
if weights_changed:
    print("Model weights have changed after training.")
else:
    print("Model weights have not changed after training.")
```

If the weights have changed, the model has been updated during training. Otherwise, it remains the same. Hence, you will get the same plot even if you change the model architecture.